# Issue with List

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm facing a problem that I don't know why it is happening. Basically, I'm trying to pass all of the elements in a List to another List in a different class. I have tried to use the variables, the get method and even the method addAll from the List class and nothing works. I keep getting empty List...

That's where the error is happening:

```
public class ChecaOrtografia
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
   Dicionario dicionario = new Dicionario();
   Gramatica gramatica = new Gramatica();
   Frase frase = new Frase();   
   public List<String> listaFrases;
   public List<Item> listaDicionario;
   public List<String> listaGramatica;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class ChecaOrtografia
     */
    public ChecaOrtografia()
    {
        listaFrases = new ArrayList<>();
        this.listaFrases.addAll(frase.listaFrases);
        listaDicionario =  new ArrayList<>();
        this.listaDicionario.addAll(dicionario.listaItens);
        listaGramatica =  new ArrayList<>();
        this.listaGramatica.addAll(gramatica.listaRegras);
    }
```

keep in mind that I have tried something like:

```
listaFrases = frase.listaFrases;
```

and

```
listaFrases = frase.getFrases();
```

That's part of my main class:

```
public class corretorGramatical 
{       
  public static void main(String [ ] args) 
  {
   Dicionario dicionario = new Dicionario();
   Gramatica gramatica = new Gramatica();
   Frase frase = new Frase();
   ChecaOrtografia checador;
   List<String> saida = new ArrayList<>();
   Item a;
   String word, category, specification, frases;
   int contador = 0;
   char code;
   Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in); 
loop:while (entry.hasNextLine()) { 
       code = entry.nextLine().charAt(0); 
   switch(code)
   {
      case 'd':
          System.out.println ("Diga quantas words seu dicionario tera");
          contador = entry.nextInt();
          entry.nextLine(); 
          for(int i = 0; i < contador; contador--) 
          {
            System.out.println ("Qual é a palavra?");
            word = entry.nextLine();
            System.out.println ("Qual a categoria?");
            category = entry.nextLine(); 
            a = new Item (word, category);
            dicionario.listaItens(a);

          }
      break;

      case 'g':   
         System.out.println ("Quantas linhas serão utilizadas para especificar a gramática?");
         contador = entry.nextInt();
         entry.nextLine();

         for(int j = 0; j < contador; contador--) 
         {
          System.out.println ("Qual é a especificação?");
          specification = entry.nextLine(); 
          gramatica.listaRegras(specification);

         } 
          break;

      case 'f':
            System.out.println ("Digite as frases que deseja checar");

            entry.nextLine();

             for(int f = 0; f < contador; contador--) 
         {
          System.out.println ("Qual é a frase?");
          frases = entry.nextLine(); 
          frase.listaFrases(frases); 
         } 
       checador = new ChecaOrtografia();
       saida = checador.checarOrtografia();
       break;

      case 's':
        break loop;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I cannot see in your code where you populate any list.

Comment: I don't see how this is supposed to work since there is no other `CeckaOrtografia` instance. If you need to copy elements between two instances you need to have two (eg a `CheckaOrtografia other`) to copy from or copy to.

Comment: Probably you are missing paraemter in your constructor with other instance of `CeckaOrtografia`

Comment: I'm copying from three different classes. I will post my main class. Maybe it will help.

Comment: The code is all right. Where are you populating your other classes list?

Comment: Where you setting actual data to these lists?

Comment: In my main class. I just use the class checkaOrtografia after populating them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're creating those classes again. They aren't the one in which you stored your data.

You'll have to pass the data from one class to another. You can either create setters or pass it in constructor.

Here's how you do it using constructors.

Make your constructor accept the 3 classes.

```
public ChecaOrtografia(Dicionario dicionario, Gramatica gramatica, Frase frase)
{
    listaFrases = new ArrayList<>();
    this.listaFrases.addAll(frase.listaFrases);
    listaDicionario =  new ArrayList<>();
    this.listaDicionario.addAll(dicionario.listaItens);
    listaGramatica =  new ArrayList<>();
    this.listaGramatica.addAll(gramatica.listaRegras);
}
```

Now pass those classes to the constructor. So we can get data from it in `ChecaOrtografia` class.

`checador = new ChecaOrtografia(dicionario, gramatica, frase);`

And remove declarations of those 3 classes in `ChecaOrtografia` class because you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new `ChecaOrtagrafia` each time before calling the `checarOrtagrafia` method. I presume that you are expecting this instance to know about the values in the `dicionario` and `gramatica` objects. But it can't possibly know those because it does not have a reference to them.

Because those two objects don't change during your loop I suspect what you want is to store a reference to them in `ChecaOrtagrafia` and just pass a `Frase` object in each time. Your class should look like this:

```
class ChecaOrtagrafia {
    private final Dicionario dicionario;
    private final Gramatica gramatica;
    public ChecaOrtagrafia(Dicionario dicionario, Gramatica gramatica) {
        this.dicionario = dicionario;
        this.gramatica = gramatica;
    }
    public List<String> checaGramatica(Frase frase) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It is unlikely that it needs its own copies of the lists in those classes. You should access the lists in the original classes when you need to use them inside `checaGramatica`.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have put nothing in the lists you are adding.  When you add a list, you are really adding the elements of the list, not the list itself.

Comment: In my main class. I just use the class checkaOrtografia after populating them all.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've shown so far you're adding an empty list to another empty list, so at time of class construction the list being added to being empty is correct behavior.

If you want to add a list to another list you need to actually populate some of its elements.

Comment: In my main class. I just use the class checkaOrtografia after populating them all.

Comment: You need to add some getters and setters to your class to access your lists from the class object, and then manipulate the lists from within your main.